# POSTing XML to a lambda in Localstack always throws 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, localstack

We have a lambda deployed to Localstack with an API gateway endpoint configured as AWS_PROXY. Invoking the Lambda with a POST works if the body is empty or contains JSON, however, sending XML in the body (regardless of the Content-Type) always returns a 502. The error in the Localstack log is:

```
localstack_1  | 2019-11-14T13:29:49:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 240, in forward
localstack_1  |     path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/apigateway/apigateway_listener.py", line 35, in forward_request
localstack_1  |     data = data and json.loads(to_str(data))
localstack_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
localstack_1  |     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
localstack_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
localstack_1  |     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
localstack_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
localstack_1  |     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
localstack_1  | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I thought AWS_PROXY integration was supposed to pass data direct to the Lambda without any attempt to decode or validate? Is there a way to set up the API gateway integration so that it will happily accept XML?

This is the function that we're using to set up API Gateway after the lambda has been deployed: https://gist.github.com/jgwconsulting/0c5597a661cbc6d29aaa346b2aed5020

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a problem with Localstack always assuming that POSTed data will be JSON and attempting to parse it to a Python dictionary.

I've created an issue to track the problem here and will attempt to make a PR to fix it if I get time: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1762